# Load animated gif after all other files on page load

Tags: javascript, html, animated-gif, pageload

I have a pretty massive animated gif (several mb!), and I don't want to hold up the rest of the elements from loading on the page before loading the gif. What technology/technique would you use to do this? I'm not asking for code here, just to be pointed in the right direction... if it's jQuery, or... something else, maybe? I'd love to know what best practices are with something like that.

Comment: The javascript event `window.onload` fires when the page is done loading. You could exclude the gif from your HTML (replace it with, e.g., an empty div) and on `window.onload` insert the gif into the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery, it is very simple :
HTML:

```
<img id='the_image' style='width:100px;height:200px' src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#the_image').attr('src','http://example.com/image.gif');
});
```

The default src I used is just a very simple inline transparent gif to hold it's place until the real image is called.

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/cmkLn87L/

Comment: Excellent--thank you. And will the jQuery load the full image after everything else on the page loads?

Comment: Yes indeed.  that is what the shortcut `$(function(){//your stuff here});` does, is execute your stuff after the page loads.

Comment: I think this should call inside  jQuery(window).load(function(){ });